# Why does $H_{y'}(x,y,y',p) = 0$ and $H_{y'y'}(x,y,y',0) \leq 0 $ imply $y$ is an optimal curve?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, hamilton-equations

I am reading Liberzon's Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control theory, and trying to understand the Maximum principle. It is currently going over the Hamiltonian formulation.

I will define some of the terms being used. We are minimizing $J(y):=\int_a^b L(x,y(x),y'(x))dx$ over any $y \in C^2([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ such that $y(a)=y_a$ and $y(b)=y_b$. We define $p:=L_{y'}(x,y,y')$ and the Hamiltonian $H(x,y,y',p):=py' - L(x,y,y')$.

Defining  $p:=L_{y'}$ and $H(x,y,y',p):=py' - L_{y'}(x,y,y',p)$. The textbook claims $H_{y'}=p-L_{y'}(x,y,y')=0$ for feasible curves $y$. So far, everything makes sense. But then the textbook claims

> This suggests that, in addition to the canonical equations (2.30),
> another necessary condition for optimality should be that H has a
> stationary point as a function of y′ along an optimal curve.

(2.30) states that a necessary condition for an optimal curve $y$ is that $y'=H_p$ and $p'=-H_y$. I understand this. But this doesn't have anything to do with the fact that $H_{y'}(x,y,y',p)=0$ for any feasible curve $y$. Is it just that for optimal curves, we have $H_{y'}(x,y,y',p)=0$, but the converse doesn't hold?

Furthemore, the textbook states the hollowing:

> Legendre’s condition tells us that, in addition, $H_{y'y'} = −L_{y'y'}
> \leq 0$ along an optimal curve [...] Thus, if the above stationary
> point is an extremum, then it is necessarily a maximum. This
> interpretation of necessary conditions for optimality moves us one
> step closer to the maximum principle.

So the book states if $H$ is extremized, then it is necessarily maximized. Firstly, $H$ was not extremized. It as extremized along the varying 3rd argument, sure, but $H$ was not extremized. Secondly, why was it necessarily maximized? From what I understand, $H_{y'}(x,y,y',p)=0$ for any feasible curve $y$. Can't we simply find a non-optimal curve $y$ such that $-L_{y'y'}(x,y,y',p) \leq 0$?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the notation that is used? I guess that $x$, $y$, $y'$ and $p$ might be the control input, state, time derivative of the state and co-state? Also what is equation (2.30)?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I rewrote my thread, apologies. This does not involve any control theory, it is just calculus of variations. Basically, I am having trouble understanding the fact that when the hamiltonian is extremized, it is necessarily maximized. I cannot find any proofs of this unfortunately.

Comment: Could you also clarify $y'$ and $L_{y'}$, I assume they mean $dy(x)/dx$ and $$\frac{\partial L(x,y,y')}{\partial y'}$$ respectively?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen You are correct. y' is the derivative of y w.r.t x, and $L_{y'}(x,y,y')$ is the partial derivative of $L$ wrt the 3rd argument, with (x,y,y') plugged in.